# How to make --version custom command in linux

Tags: bash

So, I just started to introduce myself with custom commands in Linux and created one but now I want it to be executed globally like this,
say my command is `owncmd`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Heya custom commands"
```

This works perfectly fine when I execute `$ owncmd`
but I wanted to write the version or help page like :
`$ owncmd --version` or `$ owncmd --help`

Comment: Please note that "custom command" is not a technical term. What you created is an executable file. It is executed by `bash` (since the shebang, the first line, points to the `/bin/bash` executable). This file is then marked as executable with the `x` permission. Most shell programs like that are called "scripts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a CLI (Command Line Interface).
To do this, you should parse the **command line arguments**, like `--help` and `--version`. You can access them with `$1`, `$2`, ...

Here is an example on your code :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cli_help() {
    # --help: Shows help message
    echo "
owncmd - Custom command

Usage:
    owncmd [options]

Options:
    --help / -h: Show this message and exit.
    --version / -V: Show version number and exit.
"
    exit
}

cli_version() {
    # --version: Show version
    echo "owncmd v1.0"
    exit
}

# Argument
case $1 in
    "--help"|"-h")
        cli_help
        ;;
    "--version"|"-V")
        cli_version
        ;;
esac
# Main program
echo "Heya custom commands"
```

The program look at the first argument `$1`.

- If it is `--help` or `-h`: Show an help message (function `cli_help`) and exit
- If it is `--version` or `-V`: Show version number (function `cli_version`) and exit

> ℹ️ Note: We use `-V` instead of `-v` because `-v` means "verbose mode", not "version".

If there is no `--help` or `--version`, the program shows `Heya custom commands`.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the input $1 to see whether it is -v or --version in which case you print the version and stop without executing the actual code. Idem for -h or --help.

Comment: yeah i got that